# appending in C failing, simply overwriting

Tags: c, file-io

Instead of appending "abc" (and thus eventually getting a file full of abcabcabc....), no matter how many times I run this, myfile only containst "abc".... how can I append?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char strng[10];
    strcpy(strng,"abc");
    FILE *my_file;
    my_file = fopen("myfile","a+");
    if (my_file == NULL){ printf("problem\n");}
    fwrite(strng, sizeof(strng), 1, my_file);
    printf("appending %s\n",strng);
    fclose(my_file);
}
```

Comment: An aside, not related to your problem: Don't use strcpy().  If your system has it, use strlcpy().  If you're on Windows consider StringCchCopy().  As a last resort use strncpy() but read up on its caveats.

Comment: I used the parameter order according to http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fwrite.html.  What is the correct order?

The return value is 1 (including if I execute the frwite command more than once in the program), but only one "abc" is still getting written to the file.... :/

Comment: May I suggest fprintf(my_file, "%s", strng); in place of fwrite.

Comment: No, fputs.  Error handling is bogus, too, though:  Use perror("myfile") to get e.g. myfile: Permission Denied  on stderr.  There's nothing more useless than an error message that doesn't give you any clue what the problem was, or what file the error happened with.  This isn't a windows GUI, so users probably expect better error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the fact that:

```
fwrite(strng, sizeof(strng), 1, my_file);
```

should be:

```
fwrite(strng, strlen(strng), 1, my_file);
```

it works for me.

Comment: Yeah, the original code would write '\0' into the file, and whatever he was viewing the file with later must have handled the file contents as a C string (nul-terminated).  Instead of fwrite(strlen), use fputs!

Answer (score 1):

That program works and does what you said to do: append 10 characters (`sizeof(strng)`) to file, including `\0` and rest of the array. Change `sizeof` to `strlen`.

Besides that you should not only print "problem" when you can't open file, but also not write to it.

And last problem in your code - you declared `main` as returning `int`, but end program without setting return code. If you end program correctly, always return `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 10
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

int main(int ac, char **av) {
    FILE *my_file;

    strncpy(buf, "abc", BUF_SIZE-1);
    buf[BUF_SIZE-1] = '\0';
    my_file = fopen("myfile", "a+");
    if (my_file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "problem opening file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        fwrite(buf, strlen(buf), 1, my_file);
        printf("appending %s\n", buf);
        fclose(my_file);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also don't like the FILE* declaration after the strcpy().

Comment: I don't like it too. I only modified that program to correct problems

Comment: strncpy() is actually slightly evil in that if the size of the source string is the same as the target length, it will not zero-terminate.  You can copy BUF_SIZE-1 characters and then manually write the last one as zero.  Or you can use one of the more intelligent replacements, such as strlcpy() many Unixy systems (except Linux, sadly), or StringCchCopy() on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sizeof`, use `strlen`. sizeof is 10, so you're writing "abc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0".

Comment: Actually, he's writing "abc\0..." where ... is 6 chars of random trash

Answer (score -1):

When you fopen the file, the stream position is at the beginning of the file. Surely you have to seek to the end before writing in order to get the string appended?

Comment: the "a+" mode positions the write position at the end of file.

Comment: No, he opens file in read and append mode, that's what `a+` means

Comment: Thanks for that Neil, I withdraw my answer! If this is the case then original code should be producing a bigger file, even if what's in it is not displayable. In fact looking at the file size as it increases would be a good clue to the sizeof/strlen bug.